# Regression when data is in separate clusters

Tags: regression, least-squares

I want to analyze my data with a regression of certain scores on age, but I have two age clusters: a small group of younger participants (age 20-30, n=70) and a large group of middle aged - older participants (age 50-90, n=1000). The data looks a bit like in the attached image. Intuitively I don't think a single regression is a good idea, but is there a quantifiable way to justify why/why not? Is the problem just the age gap or also the difference in n? If I run two regressions, I can't easily compare the coefficients for age. Is there another elegant way to analyze this? Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: You may want to google for "change point regression" (sorry, not enough time to put together a proper response, but in case nobody else says anything...).

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you @ChristianHennig!